# How to write for loops now in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to write for loops now in C++11?

```
for (int i{0}; i < 10; ++i) {}
```

That is how I do it now. Notice two things:

```
 1. int i{0} instead of int i = 0
 2. prefix increment
```

Are there any reasons why I should not use {} for initialization?

Comment: What's suddenly wrong with doing `int i = 0;` ?

Comment: And what was keeping you from defaulting to prefix increment before?

Comment: prefix increment works faster then postfix increment. Its recommended to use it for loops..

Comment: @Vallentin I saw it in Stroustrup's newest book also. The idea is to have one uniform way to initialize values.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: To be fair, historically the idiom in C has always been `i++` in loops.  Of course C++ is a different language; nevertheless it's difficult to break a muscle-memory habit...

Comment: Initialisation syntax is purely a matter of style; `int i(0)` was quite popular before C++11. Pre-increment has always been a good idea (although it doesn't make a jot of difference for built-in types).

Comment: Using uniform initialization might make sense when counting down, but I wouldn't worry about narrowing conversions from `0`.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Yes but by uniform I don't mean anything related to narrowing. I just mean to have one consistent style to initialize things with {}.

Answer (score 3):

There are more ways to write a for loop than there are thought of in your philosophy.

There is

```
for( auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {}
```

which uses an extra character for no good reason.  There is:

```
for( int i{}; i < 10; ++i ) {}
```

which is very squiggly.

There is the classic:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {}
```

which works just as well.  My preferred fun way is:

```
for( const int i : boost::counting_range(0, 10) ) {}
```

or some home-brew version of `boost::counting_range(0,10)`.  A cute way to make this useful is to write:

```
template<typename C>
boost::counting_range<std::size_t> indexes( C const& c ) {
  return {0, c.size()};
}
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
boost::counting_range<std::size_t> indexes( T(&)[N] ) {
  return {0, N};
}
```

which lets you iterate over the indexes of a container via:

```
for( const auto i : indexes( container ) ) {
  container[i] = i+1;
}
```

and I find that pretty slick.

Quite often you do not need indexes, however, unless you are doing parallel iteration over multiple random access containers.  A range of boost zip iterators can let you do parallel iteration over multiple containers (random or not), so long as you do the work to handle the end condition problem.

Amusingly, you could hack up `indexes` to fail to work on non-random access containers (done by testing `[std::declval<std::size_t>()]` to see if it is a valid expression), but on associative containers to iterate over keys.  Very python-esque.

Comment: FWIW: I greatly prefer the worst from `for (whatever)` over the best from `for( whatever )`

Comment: @TemplateRex you are talking about whitespace?

Comment: Yes, I hate whitespace overloading ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any reasons why I should not use {} for initialization?

Yes - clarity.  There is no reason to not write `int i = 0` as it will initialize the integer at the time of instantiation.  Other than that (the clarity of the code), there is no difference.

Additionally, if you are concerned about uniformity:

Having a variable declared outside the loop necessitates you to use equality:

```
int i = some_value;
// some code that may change i
for (i = i + 1; i < some_other_value; ++i)
{ ... }
```

If you used `{}` syntax in your loops, you would have loops like this that do not "conform" to your standard "look".  In general, write code to be readable and clear; that does not necessarily mean that you should write something in X manner every time.

> prefix increment

If you aren't using the return value for the postfix increment, the compiler will usually optimize it away (in effect becoming a prefix increment).  If you want to make sure it is clear, just default to a prefix increment when you write your loops.

Comment: Yes but {} was meant to be a uniform general way for initialization of values.

Comment: @user3111311 That doesn't necessitate using it for everything.

Comment: I personally think `int i{0}`, `int i{}`, and `int i = 0` are all equally clear.

Comment: @Zac Howland well if it does not make any difference in terms of performance, if it is question of style only, then for the sake of having consistent style and initializing things with {}, I would go with the {} initialization.

Comment: @user3111311 If everyone that was reading your code was brand new to the language, you could make that case.  However, 95% of programmers have been doing it for more than 5 minutes ...

Comment: @chris You forgot `int i(0)`, but that is a style preference.  In general, `int i = 0` (read "int i equals 0") states what it is actually doing.  Conversely, `int i{0}`, `int i{}`, and `int i(0)` all do the same thing, but "equal" without an equals sign (semantically) is not the same.